# Missing rows after splitting into chunks

Tags: python, pandas, split, chunks

I'm trying to split a data frame into **chunks of 2000 rows**, I found this code, I'm new to python btw, it works perfectly but **the last data frame** that it creates and exports to excel, its all scrambled, I mean from the first chunk to one before the last one it goes alphabetically with the exception of the last one where I find all begging letters, but it gets worse... **I'm losing some records**, I validated this with the data frame where these chunk pieces are coming from, but **after it gets split rows get lost**.

```
max_rows = 2000
dataframes = []
while len(df_count) > max_rows:
    top = df_count[:max_rows]
    dataframes.append(top)
    df_count = df_count[max_rows:]
    n=0
else:
    dataframes.append(df)

with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path + "\\" + "Emails_" + date + ".xlsx") as writer:
    for _, frame in enumerate(dataframes):
        frame = frame["Email"]
        frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="DB" + str(_+1), index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally didnt see the data frame name on the else:

```
max_rows = 2000
dataframes = []
while len(df_count) > max_rows:
    top = df_count[:max_rows]
    dataframes.append(top)
    df_count = df_count[max_rows:]
    n=0
else:
    dataframes.append(df_count)

with pd.ExcelWriter(output_path + "\\" + "Emails_" + date + ".xlsx") as writer:
    for _, frame in enumerate(dataframes):
        frame = frame["Email"]
        frame.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="DB" + str(_+1), index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

use `iloc` to split the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10**6+10).reshape(int(10**6/2)+5, 2), columns=list('AB'))

df.shape # (500005, 2)

df_list = list()
max_row = 2000
for i in range(0, len(df), 2000):
    df_list.append(df.iloc[i: i + max_row])

len(df_list) # 251
```